# express-jwt - Show permission for debug

Tags: express, express-jwt

It's possible show in error middleware what permissions are needed?

```js
//User don't have this permission
app.post("/", guard.check(permissions.$("admin")), (req, res) => {
  return new Area(req.body)
    .save()
    .then(area => {
     ///....
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

## Error middleware

I would like to show permission here in a console.log()

```js
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   
  
  if (err.code === "invalid_token") {
    return res.status(401).send("...")
  }

  if (err.code === "credentials_required") {
    return res.status(401).send("...")
  }

  //...
})
```

Comment: Provide your `guard.check` function. I guess the permission is existed in some thing like `req.user.permission`

Comment: It's a inbuilt function from `express-jwt-permissions` library.

Comment: In your error handler, just print `console.log(req.user)`.

Comment: That print all permissions sended by user logged. I would like know what permissions are needed for specific path and print them.

Comment: Wrap `guard.check` to a custom middleware, in this middleware, set require permissions to the `req` object.

Comment: Hooo!, that's a very good idea. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `guard.check` middleware into another middleware, and you can put the required permissions to `req` object, and then you can get it in the error handler middleware.

```
const customGuard = (permissions) => { // middleware factory
  return (req, res, next) => { // return a middleware function
    req.requiredPermissions = permissions; // store `permissions` in `req.requiredPermissions`
    guard.check(permissions)(req, res, next); // check your permissions with express-jwt-permissions's guard
  }
}
```

Usage, replace

```
app.post("/", guard.check(permissions.$("admin"))
...
```

by

```
app.post("/", customGuard(permissions.$("admin"))
...
```

Then, in your Error middleware

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

  console.log("Required permissions: ", req.requiredPermissions); // here

  if (err.code === "invalid_token") {
    return res.status(401).send("...")
  }

  if (err.code === "credentials_required") {
    return res.status(401).send("...")
  }

  //...
})
```